# How do I call a Java methods from one class to another class in Android development?

Tags: android

I have two classes which extend Activity and need to call another class method on main class on android development.
I did something like `subclass sub = new subclass()`. It did not work.

In 1st activity class

```
package org.me.intent_testing;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.content.Intent;

public class FirstActivity extends Activity {

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

   // Button orderButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.order);
    Button orderButton = new Button(this);
    orderButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, secondActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
      }

    });
  }
}
```

In secondActivity class

```
package org.me.intent_testing;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.content.Intent;

public class secondActivity extends Activity {

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.main);
       // setContentView(R.layout.order);


   // Button orderButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.end);
    Button orderButton =  new Button(this);
    orderButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

     @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
        finish();
      }

    });
  }
}
```

In AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     package="org.me.intent_testing">
    <application>
         <activity android:name=".FirstActivity" android:label="FirstActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
         <activity android:name=".secondActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

In R.java

```
package org.me.intent_testing;

public final class R {
    public static final class attr {
    }
    public static final class layout {
        public static final int main=0x7f020000;
    }
    public static final class string {
        public static final int app_name=0x7f030000;
    }
}
```

I have a problem linking between two classes.

Comment: post the bare minimum of the classes necessary to describe the problem so we can attempt to explain what is incorrect

Comment: do you want to return to the first activity from the second? The you should use again the Intent to go back and not to call finish().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May i know why you would want to do so?
If that method is so important to both of the classes, then create it inside a helper class (Which doesn't extend Activity) and create an object of it in both the classes, then with that object access that method.

Answer (score 2):

`SubClass sub=new SubClass();` is creating an object of class `SubClass`.

It is not a method calling.

If the method is defined in class SubClass then you can call it by using its object and dot operator.

`sub.MethodName();`

Answer (score 0):

Try just to label the required method as static. But remember that in that case the called method should not depends on any non-static member variables of methods of the class.

Comment: what not just use a non-object language then if he's going to ignore all the benefits of objects?  if he's subclassing, he's missing something bigger.

Comment: Why not use another language?  Because android doesn't really give a choice of language.  I mean, yes, there are alternatives that compile to davlik, but the tools aren't fully ready to go right under your nose, while the ndk provides neither the ability to write an entire application nor access to most of the api's.

Comment: @Chris - that was meant to be rhetorical - the point was, if you can't use the tool properly, the only choice is to use a new tool or learn to use the tool properly.  since there isn't another tool, what is left?